# How to handle multiple conditions in ngFor

Tags: angular

I am a beginner in Angular. Currently I'm working on an HTML part where some data is binding to one dropdown. My code looks like below

```
 <option *ngFor="let types of Customtype" [value]="taxtype">{{Customtype}}</option>
```

I need to display "types” based on some condtion

for eg if `type = 1` it should display as `TestCompanyA`, `type =2` then `TestCompanyB`, `type = 3` then `TestCompanyC`.

Is it possible to put `ngIf` conditions to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

***ngIf** is a sufficient solution, but I recommend ngSwitch if you have more then two conditions.

If you don't want to use additionally tag you can use custom ng-container tag, f.e:

```
<option *ngFor="let record of records" [value]="record.taxtype" [ngSwitch]="record.type">
    <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="1">TestCompanyA</ng-container >
    <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="2">TestCompanyB</ng-container >
    <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="3">TestCompanyC</ng-container >
    <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="4">TestCompanyD</ng-container >
</option>
```

From [angular-university.io](http://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-template-ng-container-ngtemplateoutlet/)

> As we can see, the ng-container directive provides us with an element
>   that we can attach a structural directive to a section of the page,
>   without having to create an extra element just for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you improve your model data structure, the template will be simpler. It also seems odd that all your option elements have the same `[value]="taxtype"`. This would mean that it doesn't matter what the user selects, the same value will be submitted with the form. I would add everything I need to the `CustomTypes` array:

```
CustomTypes = [
  {type:1, cpy:'TestCompanyA', value:'whatever you want'},
  {type:2, cpy:'TestCompanyB', value:'value for this type'},
  {type:3, cpy:'TestCompanyC', value:'...or for this company'},
];
```

Then in your template:

```
<option *ngFor="let item of CustomTypes" [value]="item.value" [label]="item.cpy"/>
```